# Jenkins to execute shell script located on remote server

Tags: jenkins

I started to pick up Jenkins recently and want to see how it will fit my working environment. One of the very first tasks I want to do is to create a Jenkins project that will run a bash script located on a remote server via ssh, not copy a local script to a remote server then run it.

I could not find much helpful information online and pretty much have no idea where to start. I am pretty sure others may have the same questions, so thought to ask it here.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the [SSH Pipeline Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/)

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try!